# parse retrieved data content from api

Tags: php

how would you guys parse the data content retrieved from a api?

I just want to be sure that I end up with the correct data..

... and how can you check if you got it all with the checksum?

eg

```
24 
DK,19,Nørresundby,57.066700,9.916700
0
```

Comment: you can't think you have provided enough information to even guess at an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which API?

If it looks like what you posted, I think you might be looking for something like this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

```
$lines = file($url);
$arr=array();
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
 $temp=explode($line,',');
 foreach ($temp as $item)
     array_push($arr,$item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the API, clarkk. Is the API using REST, SOAP? What about data, XML or JSON?

As for parsing the snippet you sent, i would just use explode().

Answer (score 0):

as the other guys said, it depends on what API are you talking about because we need to know in which format the data is delivered to you. If it is plain text you can do this:

```
<?php
$data_received = "DK,19,Nørresundby,57.066700,9.916700";
$data = explode(",", $data_received);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

this will get that text organized in a array format named $data; and print it.